# Shell - how to go to a location that is just returned by previous command?

Tags: bash

After I do

```
$ which play
$ /Users/username/local/play/play
```

Is there a way that I can access the shown directory quickly without manually typing the directory by hand? Just curious :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cd $(dirname $(which play))
```

Or, immediately after running `which play`, you can do:

```
cd $(dirname $(!!))
```

Comment: Just to clarify, `!!` does not print the output of the previous command, but actually reruns the previous command.  So if you try this trick for a command with side effects or non-constant behavior, you might get unexpected results